Vaadin CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler in Spring context doesn't work
I have a Spring Boot 3.2.5 and Vaadin 24.3.10 project. I want to handling login erros in the Vaadin-suggested login process. It means I define a class what extend the SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler class, and set this class in SecurityConfig.
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends VaadinWebSecurity
{

    private final AppUserRepository userRepository;
    private final CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler;

    public SecurityConfig(AppUserRepository appUserRepository, CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler) {
        this.userRepository = appUserRepository;
        this.failureHandler = failureHandler;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                    auth.requestMatchers(
                            AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher(HttpMethod.GET, "/images/*.png")).permitAll();
                })
                .formLogin(form -> form
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .failureHandler(failureHandler)  
                    .failureUrl("/login?error")
                    .permitAll())
                .logout(logout -> logout.permitAll())
                .exceptionHandling(e -> e.authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login")))
                .headers(httpSecurityHeadersConfigurer -> httpSecurityHeadersConfigurer.frameOptions(HeadersConfigurer.FrameOptionsConfig::disable))
        ;

        super.configure(httpSecurity);
        setLoginView(httpSecurity, LoginView.class);
    }


and the CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler class:
@Service
@Slf4j
public class CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {

    @Autowired
    private LogService logService;

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) throws
        IOException, ServletException
    {
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        log.error("Wrong login: {}", username);
        logService.auditLog("UNKNOWN", LogTypes.SEC_ERR, "Wrong login: " + username);
        super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);
    }
}

I need the Spring contex, because the LogService in CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler use the JPA. But this configuration doesn't work. If I don't use LogService and the create the CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler by new, then it works correctly.
...
         .failureHandler(new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler())
...

I tried to look a solution, because I need the persistent audit log, but I have no idea. I need a solution whitch help me use the Spring context in this setup.

So the solution is the order of the parameters.
It was the original:
                .formLogin(form -> form
                .loginPage("/login")
                .failureHandler(failureHandler)  
                .failureUrl("/login?error")
                .permitAll())

The working version:
                .formLogin(form -> form
                .failureUrl("/login?error")
                .loginPage("/login")
                .failureHandler(failureHandler)  
                .permitAll())

As you see, if the

failureHandler

is not the last, then it is not working.
